# How to add link2sd to cyanogenmod custom_backup_list.txt?

Tags: cyanogenmod, link2sd

I'm using link2sd installed on `/data`

Every time I update the CyanogenMod rom I need to recreate the scripts and reboot to recover all the applications that are on the ext3 partition.

¿Can I edit the `/etc/custom_backup_list.txt` file to preserve the link2sd scripts?